# What are the assumptions when dealing with the EM Algorithm in order to calculate $f_{\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta}(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, st.statistics, algorithms, expectation

Consider the [EM Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm). In order to apply it, we are given the observed data $\textbf{X}$ (generated by some distribution depending on some parameters), which can be a vector, a matrix or a matrix of matrices (when we are dealing with random matrices theory). We are also given a latent variable $Y$ whose unobserved data corresponds to a vector $\textbf{Y}$.

Based on them, the user postulates a joint probability density function for $\textbf{X}$ and $\textbf{Y}$, denoted by $f_{\textbf{X},\textbf{Y}}(\textbf{X},\textbf{Y}|\theta)$ (which can be seen as the Likelihood function of the complete data), where $\theta$ is a vector of parameters. Consequently, it remains to determine the distribution of $f_{\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta}(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta)$ with the purpose of calculating the expected value step.

My first question is: how do we generally determine $f_{\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta}(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta)$?

According to the conditional probability definition, we know that
\begin{align*}
f_{\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta}(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta) = \frac{f_{\textbf{X},\textbf{Y}}(\textbf{X},\textbf{Y}|\theta)}{f_{\textbf{X}}(\textbf{X}|\theta)}
\end{align*}
Consequently, if we know $f_{\textbf{X}}(\textbf{X}|\theta)$, we do also know $f_{\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta}(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta)$.

Then my second question is: do we always know $f_{\textbf{X}}(\textbf{X}|\theta)$?

Otherwise, how do we calculate $f_{\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta}(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X},\theta)$? Do we assume a distribution for $\textbf{Y}$?

The same question has been asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/642243/what-are-the-assumptions-when-dealing-with-the-em-algorithm-in-order-to-calculat), but no response has been given so far.

Comment: Could it be that you meant $f_{\textbf{X}}(\textbf{x}\mid\theta)$ rather than $f_{\textbf{X}}(\textbf{X}\mid\theta) \text{?}$